# Create View In BaseViewController and use in SubviewController

Tags: swift, xcode

Hi I Use BaseViewController and my view inherited from it , I Create one view in this and I want To use that in other views , but its just exist in first page and in other page is nil

BaseViewController.swift

```
import UIKit  

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    var ExampleView : UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let ExampleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0 , y: 0 ,width:100 ,height:100)
        view.addSubview(ExampleView)
    }
}
```

FirstVC

```
class FirstVC : BaseViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ExampleView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

in FirstVC It has value but in secondVC I use Same FirstVC but it is nil  (go to secondVC with segue from FirstVC and secondVC inherits from BaseViewController too)

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't call super.viewDidLoad() in the viewDidLoad() override of FirstVC
2. You never assign ExampleView to the property in your BaseViewController class. Instead you created a local variable inside the scope of the viewDidLoad method (using the same name) shadowing the instance property.

To fix your problem:

BaseViewController.swift

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    var ExampleView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ExampleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        view.addSubview(ExampleView)
    }
}
```

FirstVC:

```
class FirstVC: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ExampleView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I do this But still not work , I don't have problem with firstVC , in secondVC ExampleView is nil

Comment: Then post the code of SecondVC, I only see FirstVC and BaseViewController